# Ansible selectattr and map with optional fields

Tags: ansible

I am trying create an ansible playbook to set up multiple nodes. In my variables I have a the following structure:

```
nodes:
  - nodename: foonode
    othervalue: foo
    booleanvalue: true
  - nodename: barnode
    othervalue: bar
```

The booleanvalue is optional and shoutd default to false. Later it might be possible to have more optional values. For now I only want to use the optional boolean value.

```
- name: "Debug"
  debug:
    msg: "Do something useful here"
  when:  when: nodes | selectattr('nodename', 'equalto', ansible_hostname) | map(attribute='booleanvalue') | first | bool
```

This code snippet works as long as booleanvalue exists. But it does not work for barnode. As I am using 2.9.6 I cannot use map(attribute='booleanvalue', default='whatever'). Is there another or better way to make it work with optional values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
nodes:
  foonode:
    othervalue: foo
    booleanvalue: true
  barnode:
    othervalue: bar
```

Then, the condition is trivial

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "Do something useful here"
    when: nodes[inventory_hostname]['booleanvalue'] | default(false)
```

<sup>not tested</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. This works and is easy to understand.